# Setting a cron job for a Meteor Method

Tags: javascript, meteor, cron

I have this piece of code:

```
    Meteor.methods({
  GetTickerInfo: function(){

    Future = Npm.require('fibers/future');
    var myFuture = new Future();

    kraken.api('Ticker', {"pair": 'ETHXBT'}, function(error, data) {
        if(error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
        else {
            console.log(data.result);
            console.log(data.result.XETHXXBT.a);

            myFuture.return(data.result);

        }
    });

    console.log("EHEHEHEHEHHEEH");
    console.log(myFuture.wait());
    return myFuture.wait();

  }
});
```

What it does it calls an API, gets some data back and when it's done it returns the data to the client so I can visualise in the graph. For now its a MANUAL click button on the client side which calls the method, does the job, and returns the data.

I would like to schedule a cron to do that. So every 5 sec make a API call and return the data back to the client (because there is where I visualise it). All the cron jobs are working with specific functions but I can't access the this function GetTickerInfo because it is defined and in the scope of Meteor.methods.

How can I call it be a cron job, but also leave the occasional Meteor Call from the client side when I want to manualy refresh in the given moment?

Can anyone show how would they implement this with for e.g. CRON package: `percolatestudio/meteor-synced-cron`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to be outside of the methods scope and I would personally do:

```
SyncedCron.add({
      name: 'GetTickerInfo cron',
      schedule: function(parser) {
        return parser.text('every 5 seconds');
      },
      job: function() {
        Meteor.call('GetTickerInfo');
          }
        });

SyncedCron.start()
```

Comment: Hey, this works! Although I'm not getting the info passed back to the client wheres with the meteor.call on the client side I had it back as a result. How do you propose I push the data back to the client?

This is what I have on the client side:
`  Meteor.call("GetTickerInfo", function(error, result){
      if(error){
        console.log("error", error);
      }
      if(result){
        console.log("ALO");
        console.log(result);`

Comment: SyncedCron is something executed server side. Perhaps it could be more appropiate for you to call from the client a method every 5 seconds with setInterval?
Anyway if I was helpful, you could vote my answer as best answer.

Comment: Sure thing sir. You solved all my inquiries! Thank you! :)